# How to set up the environment of a Python child process in Windows

Tags: python, windows

I have to launch a Python process from a C++ executable using the CreateProcess Windwos AP I.
When I independently run the Python process, the relative paths for importing the libraries work well
but when I run the same Python process from a C++ executable, the relative paths for importing the libraries do not work because they will be taking the path relative to the directory in which the C++ executable is kept and not in the directory where the Python file is.
So is there a way to set up the environment of a Python process when launching it through the CreateProcess Windows API

Comment: Set the `lpCurrentDirectory` parameter accordingly. It will be used to resolve relative paths (if a program doesn't set the current working directory explicitly later)

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. I will check this out. And if it is correct I will report back in you can mark this as an answer and I will accept it. Once again thank you for your prompt response

Comment: Paths relative to the working directory can be used for arguments passed on the command line. However, it's a design error if your Python script(s) use the working directory to find private resources. Resource files should be located relative to the *script* directory.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Is the script directory not the same as the working directory? At least I am setting the working directory to be the same as the script directory when I'm invoking the Python script from the C++ program

Comment: Michael - the current directory parameter that you have mentioned works  when I import a Python module like this "sys.insert.path(0,"../package1")  followed by "import modul1e" but does not work for "import package1.module1"). Shouldn't both of them work - they work identically if I invoke the script through Python IDE like Pycharm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been resolved in the comments by Michael. Reproducing the comment below
Set the lpCurrentDirectory parameter accordingly. It will be used to resolve relative paths (if a program doesn't set the current working directory explicitly later) –